# which approach will be better - multi-threading example

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, concurrency, memory-efficient

I would like to know if there is any difference between these two approaches of performing a task using multi-threading in Java 7:

Brief requirement - I have to process 200 records, simultaneously, and each record should be processed once only.

Approach 1:

```
public class Counter {

    private static int count = -1;
    private static final Object lock = new Object();

    public static int getCount() {
        synchronized (lock) {
            return ++count;
        }
    }
}



public class Task implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int count = 0;
        while((count = Counter.getCount()) < 200) {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " " + count);
            // process record # count
        }
    }
}

public class Tester {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            service.execute(new Task());
        }
        service.shutdown();
        service.awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(end - start);
    }
}
```

Approach 2:

```
public class Task2 implements Runnable {

    private int i = 0;

    public Task2(int i) {
        super();
        this.i = i;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " " + i);
        // process record # i
    }
}

public class Tester2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10); 
        for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
            service.execute(new Task2(i));
        }
        service.shutdown();
        service.awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(end - start);
    }
}
```

Both runs fine and produces same output and takes almost same time.
However 200 number taken in example code will be in billions in actual scenario. Please suggest which one will be better in terms of memory and CPU etc.

Thanks.

Edit - adding approach 3 based on Jimmy T.'s suggestion.

Approach 3:

```
public class Tester3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        int processedRecords = 0;
        int totalRecords = 200;
        int recordsPerThread = 10;
        boolean continueProcess = true;

        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

        while(continueProcess) {
            int startIndex = processedRecords;
            int endIndex = startIndex + recordsPerThread - 1;
            if (endIndex >= totalRecords - 1) {
                endIndex = totalRecords - 1;
                continueProcess = false;
            }
            processedRecords = processedRecords + recordsPerThread;
            service.submit(new Task3(startIndex, endIndex));
        }
        service.shutdown();
        service.awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    }
}


public class Task3 implements Runnable {

    private int startIndex = 0;
    private int endIndex = 0;

    public Task3(int startIndex, int endIndex) {
        super();
        this.startIndex = startIndex;
        this.endIndex = endIndex;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("processing records from " + startIndex + " to " + endIndex);
    }
}
```

Comment: 200 to billions is a large jump.  Too large for us to comment on, imo.  You'll have to be more specific.  In particular "billions" of threads cannot be run on a single systems, so you likely have to think of some way of distributing your problem over multiple system.  That's well beyond what StackOverflow was designed to answer.

Comment: No, not billions of threads, billions of records (in 10-15 threads).

Comment: Oooh, well honestly I still can't say.  I'd need to know what your "task" actually does, and a bit more about the hardware too.  Generally, ExecutorService is preferred over making your own threads, if that's what you are asking.

Comment: Is this an exact use case scenario, or just a generic example? It may be more scalable to distribute a large workload between different systems via queue (similar to approach #1). I terms of performance, it really depends on what you're doing in your runnable, but I don't think approach 2 is practical unless you're running this task over days...

Comment: @coffeeaddict, it's real use case. Running for days is fine.

Comment: Ultimately, performance will be implementation specific. From a memory perspective, you probably want to use an object pool to store instances of your runnable if you go with approach #2. From a CPU perspective, I think this is a moot point. You probably want to use as much CPU as possible while keeping it stable. This can be controlled using either method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Brief requirement - I have to process 200 records, simultaneously, and each record should be processed once only.
>
> However 200 number taken in example code will be in billions in actual scenario.

As always, the answer is "it depends". Unless your tasks are extremely fast, the overhead of either synchronization or object creation shouldn't matter. Note that an `ExecutorService` has to do some synchronization internally, too.

You could avoid the synchronization and simplify your code by using an `AtomicInteger` counter. But I'd most probably go for a `Queue` and a a couple of `Runnable`s `poll`ing it as it's simple and gives you a lot of flexibility:

- you could use a `PriorityQueue` if you wanted to prioritize some records
- you could create your own queue if storing all records in memory would be too expensive (your queue could fetch them from files or DB or whatever)

---

You could pre-fill your queue or use a `BlockingQueue` filled by a producer. The content of the queue could be the record indexes or (probably better) the records themselves.

Every task polls the queue and terminates when it's empty.

```
public class Task3 implements Runnable {
    @Override public void run() {
        while (true) {
            final Integer i = queue.poll();
            if (i==null) break;    
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " " + i);
            // process record # i
        }
    }
}
```

You create just a limited number of them to keep all your core's busy.

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10); 
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) service.execute(new Task3());
```

Comment: Probably use a bounded BlockingQueue and let the producer wait when capacity is full. I like the queue solution if only because you can keep adding consumers, or scale out on a bigger scale (like multiple servers hitting a JMS queue)

Comment: Thanks. Task is actually going to be extremely fast.

Comment: Hi maaartinus, thanks for AtomicInteger suggestion. Could you please provide more details on Queue, Runnable and Polling solution? Thanks.

Comment: Priority is not required.

Answer (score 1):

Well, all i can see is that in approach 1, there is one more Object to be handled (Conter) by the JVM, and inside the Counter there is a synchronized block, that aways cost more the thread scheduler, because it will have to handle the acess to the variable count:

```
 public static int getCount() {
        synchronized (lock) {
            return ++count;
        }
    }
```

So, it seems approach 2 is a little better if we talk about processing and performance.

Comment: Depends on the overhead of creating a new Task instance (in the OPs case, this is in billions) vs getting through a one liner synchronized block. Of course, instead of using Counter, I'd just use AtomicInteger and let the java implementation do the work and call it a day

Comment: Nice, didn't think about that. Thank you for improving the perspective

Answer (score 1):

The second approach is better because you don't synchronize all threads but I would recomment that you process more than one record per Task2 instance.